# React Native hooks, useRef and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to translate a **Class Component** into a **Functional** one with React Native.

My `Search` component lets the user search for a film name and I'm making an API call to show him all corresponding films.

Here is my class component :

```js
class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.searchedText = "";
        this.page = 0
        this.totalPages = 0
        this.state = {
            films: [],
            isLoading: false
        }
    }

    _loadFilms() {
        if (this.searchedText.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ isLoading: true })
            getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(this.searchedText, this.page+1).then(data => {
                this.page = data.page
                this.totalPages = data.total_pages
                this.setState({
                    films: [ ...this.state.films, ...data.results ],
                    isLoading: false
                })
            })
        }
    }

    _searchTextInputChanged(text) {
        this.searchedText = text
    }

    _searchFilms() {
        this.page = 0
        this.totalPages = 0
        this.setState({
            films: [],
        }, () => {
            this._loadFilms()
        })
    }

render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.main_container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textinput}
                    placeholder='Titre du film'
                    onChangeText={(text) => this._searchTextInputChanged(text)}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this._searchFilms()}
                />
                <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => this._searchFilms()}/>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.films}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <FilmItem film={item}/>}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    onEndReached={() => {
                        if (this.page < this.totalPages) {
                            this._loadFilms()
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
render() {
      return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text) => this._searchTextInputChanged(text)}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this._searchFilms()}
                />
                <Button title='Search' onPress={() => this._searchFilms()}/>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.films}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <FilmItem film={item}/>}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    onEndReached={() => {
                        if (this.page < this.totalPages) {
                            this._loadFilms()
                        }
                    }}
                />
                {this._displayLoading()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I **translate the following with hooks :**

- `this.page` and `this.totalPages` ? is useRef the solution ?
- in `_searchFilms()` I'm using `setState` callback to make a new API call when my film list is empty (because it's a new search). But doing it right after doesn't work because `setState` is asynchronous. 
  But I can't find a way to do it with hooks.

I think `useEffect` could do this but :

- I only want to make this API call when my `film` list is empty, because I call `_searchFilms()` for a **new search**.
- `_loadFilms()` is called on user scroll to add more films to the FlatList (for the same search) so I can't clear `this.films` in this case.

Here is how I translated it so far :

```js
const Search = () => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
    // handle pagination
    const page = useRef(0);
    const totalPages = useRef(0);
    // handle api fetch
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


    const loadFilmsFromApi = () => {
        getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(searchText, page + 1).then((data) => {
            page.current = data.page;
            totalPages.current = data.total_pages;
            setFilms(films => [...films, ...data.results]);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
    };

    const searchFilm = () => {
        if (searchText.length > 0) {
            page.current = 0;
            totalPages.current = 0;
            setFilms([]);
            // HERE MY Films list won't be cleared (setState asynchronous)
            loadFilmsFromApi();

            // after the api call, clear input
            setSearchText('');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(page, totalPages, "Film number" + films.length);
    }, [films]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right path. As for `totalPages` and `page`, having it as a `ref` makes sense if you want to maintain that values between different renders ( when setting state )

```js
const Search = () => {

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
  // handle pagination
  const page = useRef(0);
  const totalPages = useRef(0);
  // handle api fetch
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
  // This can be invoked by either search or user scroll
  // When pageNum is undefined, it means it is triggered by search
  const loadFilmsFromApi = (pageNum) => {
    console.log("APPEL", 'loadFills');
    getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(searchText, pageNum ? pageNum + 1 : 1).then((data) => {
      page.current = data.page;
      totalPages.current = data.total_pages;
      
      setFilms(films => {
        if(pageNum) {
          return [...films, ...data.results];
        } else {
          return [data.results];
        }
      });
      
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
   if (searchText.length > 0) {
      page.current = 0;
      totalPages.current = 0;
      
      setFilms([]);
      loadFilmsFromApi();
      // after the api call, clear input
      setSearchText('');
    }
  
  }, [searchText, loadFilmsFromApi]);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(page, totalPages, "Nombre de film " + films.length);
  }, [films]);

  return ( <
    div > Search < /div>
  );

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "ref makes sense if you want to maintain that values between different renders" - embarrassingly, I didn't know that that the values would persist between renders when using useRef. Thanks for that

Comment: @Chev There is always a first time for everything. You only get to know once you start using them

Comment: I add more explanation on how my component works. The problem is that when I'm calling `setFilms([])` and then making my API call, the `films` won't be clear because `setState` is asynchronous. And why did you pass `loadFilmsFromApi` in the array along with `searchText` in `useEffect` ?

Comment: I have passed it as part of the dependency list as it is one of the dependencies which gets invoked in the use effect. You can find more info in this article - https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: When you set, 'setFilms([]);' in `searchFilm`, the next cycle of render will have an empty list, which will be really fast compared to the time request comes back. So the behavior should be almost similar

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear what your question is, but it sounds like you want to clear films state before you fire off the query to the api? I am also not clear on the use of useRef here - [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is simply a way to get a reference to an element so it's easy to access it later - like get a reference to a div and be able to access it easily via `myDivRef.current`

```
const = myDivRef = useRef;
...
<div ref={myDivRef}/>
```

If that is the case, then I would simply set the state of films once in the return of the API call. WRT to the refs, it seems like you this should just be normal variables, or possible state items in your function.

**UPDATE**:
After clearing up the goal here, you could simply add a parameter to `loadFilmsFromApi` to determine if you should append or overwrite:

```
const loadFilmsFromApi = (append) => {
    getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(searchText, page + 1).then((data) => {
        page.current = data.page;
        totalPages.current = data.total_pages;

        if (append) {
            setFilms({
                films: this.state.films.concat(data.results)
            });
        } else {
            setFilms({
                films: data.results
            });
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
    })
};
```

Comment: One of the use cases of `useRef` is to access DOM elements. The other use case is when you want to keep track of mutable references

Comment: Never used it like that before - thanks for the comment

Comment: Yes I want to clear films state before I fire off the query to the api but only in my `searchFilm` method because it's for a new search. When I update `films` in `loadFilmsFromApi` I'm only adding films so I don't want to clear the list.